# Variable numérica se muestra en pantalla con paréntesis, como quitar el paréntesis y mantener el valor del interior en Python

Tags: python, variables, comparaciones

Tengo dos varíales, donde les deberían llegar valores tipo INT, al realizar un print estas muestran en pantalla (888), el numero en paréntesis.

```
  print(variable1)   
     (999)   
  print(variable2)   
      (555)
```

El problema que al realizar comparaciones, sale un TypeError:

```
  if int(variable1) and int(variable2) <= 766:
        print("Acción ejecutada")
        TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

   else:
        print("Otra cosa")
        TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

El problema de las variables pueden ser los (), por eso al compararlas con un numero aparece el error.
Si es así, Como puedo quitarle el paréntesis a una variable y mantener el valor que contiene en su interior.
Si no influye el paréntesis, que podría ser?

NOTA: Aclarar que estoy usando selenium, además desde la pagina el valor ya contiene el ()

```
 variable1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//....').text
         print(variable1)
          (333)
```

Estoy usando Python.

Comment: Bienvenido ErDog! El error que pones no se corresponde a lo que has escrito, luego tienes que estar en otra parte del código. Lo que tienes aquí está correcto, el error te pone `'<='` "menor o igual que" y tu estás usando `>=` "mayor o igual que" luego el error no viene de ahí.

Comment: Gracias Rubiales Alberto, Solo fue error de tipeo,  pude ser los paréntesis? La variable muestra en pantalla (111) y al compararla con un numero este compara, (111) <= 100

Comment: Tu variable que contiene `"(999)"` es una cadena y no un número. Debes quitarle los paréntesis y convertir a entero lo que queda. Esto puede ser sencillo si hacemos la suposición de que los paréntesis aparecen solo al inicio y fin de la cadena y que lo que encierran es un número válido. Bastaría hacer `valor = int(variable[1:-1])`

Comment: Gracias abulafia, Exactamente estimado, ese era el problema, esa variable era una cadena y no un numero, muy agradecido por su ayuda.